Calling Subroutine to remove formulas causes workbook to "strobe"
I have a workbook that allows our department to create a new Weekly Briefing Sheet, and some of the data is populated by formulas.
I have added a line into my Email PDF subroutine .Range("A1:F110").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Path & File which removes the formulas but leaves the data intact.
Sub Email_PDF()
Call DeleteSomeFormulas
Dim Path As String, File As String
Path = "Z:\Team\Staff Communications\Staff Briefings\Staff Briefings 2024" & "\"
With ActiveWorkbook: File = Left(.Name, InStr(.Name, ".") - 1): End With
With ActiveSheet
    File = "QF28 - Staff Information - Weekly Briefing week commencing " & .Name
    With .PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
    End With
    .Range("A1:F110").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Path & File
End With
With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .Display
    .To = "Technicians"
    .Subject = "Briefing Sheet"
    .Body = "Please find attached the latest Briefing Sheet."
    .Attachments.Add Path & File & ".pdf"
End With
End Sub

However, whenever I run the Email PDF it does what it is supposed to, but the whole workbook looks like a strobe light until all the formulas on the worksheet have been removed - 1 - 2 seconds.
Can someone suggest either a change to the code, or what alternative I might use to remove all the formulas for the active worksheet when I am running the Email PDF Macro
I have tried googling other usable code without a great deal of success.

Turn off screen updating using application.screenupdating = false while the code is running.

Just remember to turn screen updating back on at the end of the macro.

That shouldn't be necessary - it should just happen.

I have added the line here:  '.Range("A1:F110").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Path & File
Application.ScreenUpdating = False''    Thje screen still "shimmers" slightly, but is certianly better than it was.  Have I added the code in the right place?

You want it at the start of the code.

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False' added to very start of Email PDF routine and screen no longer "Shimmers" or "Strobes".
Adjusted the DeleteSomeFormulas to allow Screen Updating to be stopped/started.
Sub DeleteSomeFormulas()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Call fileProtection(False)
    Range("A2:F9").Copy
    Range("A2:F9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Call fileProtection(True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub


If the macro errors with no error control when using Application.ScreenUpdating = False you can end up with an instance of Excel which you can't easily use. You can use On Error GoTo ExitSub before the Application.ScreenUpdating = False and add ExitSub: Application.ScreenUpdating = True at the end of the Sub as one way to avoid this.

If you're going to use Application.ScreenUpdating, make sure that you have error handling which turns the ScreenUpdating back on.  If your code errs out (and any code can err out), you need to make sure that the ScreenUpdating gets turned back on.
